# ubuntu server - does not run on static ip

Tags: networking, server, static-ip

I am totally new to ubuntu server(did not work with any server before). I have installed  LAMP(apache2, mysql, php) on ubuntu server(16.04.1 LTS). It works all correctly. It has `192.168.0.22` Ip.

On other computers, there are windows 7 installed(`192.168.0.45`).

When i write  ubuntu server's ip in windows browser, it works but when i write localhost on windows browser it does not work but it does work on ubuntu server.

So now I want to set custom/static ip on ubuntu server this `192.168.0.11` its totally does not work neither in ubuntu server browser or neither ping neither ping www.google.com

my `/etc/network/interfaces` is something like this

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

I dont have `eth0`. I did everything to find it but did not find

How i tried to change ubuntu server ip to static

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
   address 192.168.0.11
   netmask 255.255.255.0  #<-- random i dont know what should i have to write here
   gateway 192.168.0.1    #<-- random i dont know what should i have to write here
   network 192.168.0.10   #<-- random i dont know what should i have to write here
   broadcast 192.168.0.12 #<-- random i dont know what should i have to write here
   nameserver 8.8.8.8     #<-- random i dont know what should i have to write here
```

my `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.1.1  web

#The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable host
::1       localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Repeat I dont have etho

**Command :**

```
root@web: # ipconfig -a

enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet hwaddr .......
          broadcast MULTICAST MTU:15000.....
           ... 0... 0...0 ..
           .................................
           .................................

enp2s0    Link encap:ethernet hwaddr .......
          inet addr:192.168.0.22 bcast :192.168.0.255 mask 255.255.255
          inet6 addr fe80::..:...
          ...........................
          ...........................
          ...........................

lo        link encap:local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask :255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr:  ::1/128 Scope:host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU :numbera
          rx pckts :228 bla bla bal
          ..........
          ..........
```

I have put almost all information. If you need any further information tell me. Ty for helping.

Comment: "When i write ubuntu server's ip in windows browser, it works but when i write localhost on windows browser it does not work but it does work on ubuntu server."   So, it sounds like everything was working correctly before you started modifying your configuration?

Comment: Don't worry about eth0 your interface is called enp2s0. Have you tried restarting your interface with `ifdown enp2s0 && ifup enp2s0`? I would comment out the network and broadcast lines too.

Comment: oohh sorry.. it works correcty with 192.168.0.22 which is server ip(this ip is dafualt bu server installation), this ip work also on windows. I want to have this server ip 192.168.0.11

Comment: @Arronical yes i did

Comment: As Arronical notes, your network and broadcast lines are incorrect.  network would be `192.168.0.0` and broadcast `192.168.0.255`,  but you can just omit them instead.

Comment: so should i do like this 
`auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
   address 192.168.0.10
   netmask 255.255.255.0  
   gateway 192.168.0.1   
   network 192.168.0.0 
   broadcast 192.168.0.255
   nameserver 8.8.8.8`
 and  getway ? should i add ?

Comment: @user4556274 should i configure`/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: `/etc/hosts` is used for *local name resolution*.  It is not relevant to the specific question of setting a static IPv4 address.

Comment: ok last thing,  i want to be clear should i do like this `auto enp2s0 iface enp2s0 inet static address 192.168.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.0.1 network 192.168.0.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255 nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you amend the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to read:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0
    iface enp2s0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0  
    gateway 192.168.0.181
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Get the system to re-read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup -v enp2s0
```

The -v for verbose should produce some output that tells us if the address was given successfully. Test:

```
ping -c3 192.168.0.181
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns, you are all set.

Comment: gateway 192.168.0.118  ? is it  181 ?

Comment: Oops! Cleaning my bifocals now! Editing answer next! Sorry.

Comment: why didn't you write network and broadcast ?

Comment: It's not needed. Is it working as expected now?

Comment: i tried with `sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup -v enp2s0` -v verbose gives me strange result `rtnetlink answers : Cannot assign requested address Parsing file /etc/network/interfaces.d/enp2s0.........` after it i reboot then  i tried `ping -c3 192.168.0.181 `  3 packects transmitted, 3 ercived, 0% loss, time 2003ms   then i  try ping -c3 8.8.8.8 rslt 3 packets transmitted, 0 recived , 100% packet loss.. then i try with ping -c www.ubuntu.com  result is ping:unknow host www.ubuntu.com same thing i tried with google same result i got. I dont know whats wrong is ?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that you included -v verbose and an actual part of the command? That's not what I suggested.

Comment: oops sorry  i convinced that is in code... sorry  btw i have solved problem using different address, i do not what problem had with 192.168.0.11. i changed to  192.168.0.50.

Comment: ok. i did. ty for helping. i have one more question My server is running on 192.168.0.50 on LAN from my workstation. But now i want to access it  from my house

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0
    iface enp2s0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0  #depends on your network class of address
    gateway 192.168.0.1    #address of the server that allow you to connect internet or other networks.
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8     #domain names resolver 8.8.8.8 it's google's public dns
```

then

```
$ sudo touch /etc/network/interfaces.d/enp2s0
```

then

```
$ sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup enp2s0
```

Comment: its work but i am not able to  connect to the network (ping google.com)

Comment: it is not connected to internet now.. what i do  ?

Comment: Make sure that the `gateway` line gives your actual gateway IPv4 address.    If you don't know your gateway address, but your windows machines have internet connectivity, run `ipconfig` on one of the windows machines to see what the gateway address is.

Comment: gateway predefined     192.168.0.181

Comment: I tried everything but does not work :(

Comment: What do other devices, Windows computers, iPads, iPods, etc., on the same network show as the gateway?

Comment: my windows pc shows me 192.168.0.181 and i check on server using netstat -rn it is showing me same 192.168.0.181

Comment: server let me use custom ip but it is not acessing  the internet...  i  use command ping www.google.com  but does not do anything

Comment: 192.168.0.181 is the *gateway* address on the Windows PC, Is the correct? The *gateway*?

Comment: yes it is 192.168.0.181

Comment: try `route -n` and past the output

Comment: i found one thing in resolv.conf `nameserver 192.168.0.10  serach comanpyname.local` btw i want set address `192.168.0.11` not `192.168.0.10`

Comment: try this out: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280431